# $p(x)$ divided by $x-c$ has remainder $p(c)$? [Polynomial Remainder Theorem]

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

This is from Pinter, *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, p.265.

Given $p(x) \in F[x]$ where $F$ is a field, I would like to show that $p(x)$ divided by $x-c$ has remainder $p(c)$.

This is easy if $c$ is a root of $p$, but I don't see how to prove it if $c$ is not a root.

Comment: If $\dfrac{p(x)}{x-c}=q(x)+\dfrac{r}{x-c}$, then $p(x)=(x-c)q(x)+r$. Now let $x=c$...

Comment: Personally I think the following would be a better title, but I’ll leave it up to you: “How to prove polynomial remainder theorem when $c$ is not a root?” and I’d tag it accordingly

Answer (score 7):

[Division Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) $\rm\:\!\Rightarrow p(x) = q(x)\ (x\!-\!c) + r,\ r\in F.\, $  Eval at $\rm\ x\! =\! c\ \Rightarrow\ p(r)=r.\ \bf\small QED$

Therefore $\rm\ x - c\ |\ p(x)-p(c)\ $ in $\rm\:R[x],\,$ $\rm \ \forall\ p\in R[x]\:,\ \forall\ rings\ R\quad $ **[Factor Theorem]**

Said equivalently $\rm\ p(x)\equiv p(c)\ \pmod{\!x - c}$

or, in other words, $\rm\ x\equiv c \,\Rightarrow\, p(x)\equiv p(c)\,\ $ [also follows by [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)]

E.g. casting nines: mod $\rm 9\!:\  10\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ N= p(10)\equiv p(1) \equiv $ sum of digits of $\rm\, N\,$ in radix $10$.

Note how the result is much clearer in the language of congruence arithmetic.

**Remark** $\ $ The shift automorphism $\rm\ x\to x+c\ $ reduces the proof of the Factor Theorem to the "obvious" special case $\rm\:c = 0,\:$ e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17809/242) and my [sci.math post appended below](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/042ac4bb7eb096c2?hl=en&dmode=source). However, this approach is a bit risky pedagogically since such a proof is not completely rigorous without knowledge that such maps are ring automorphisms. It is essential that students learn how to make rigorous (ring-theoretically!) prior informal arguments about substitution, changing "variables", etc. Much subtlety lies here, e.g. even in the informal notation for polynomials, such as $\rm\: P(X\!+\!c)\:$ below. This automorphism is the essence behind Patrick's answer, and is also implicitly in Pierre's. Of course such shifting is yet another example of *transformation-based* problem-solving, cf. my [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93628/242) on analogously applying a shift so that Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion applies.

> asdf qjohnny2...@yahoo.com wrote to sci.math on 29 Mar 2006 (*paraphrased*)
>
> > How do you prove that for a polynomial  P(X)
> >
> > $\rm P(c)=0\ \Rightarrow\ X-c\ |\ P(X)\ $ i.e. $\rm\ (X-c)\ Q(X)\ =\ P(X)\ $  for some $\rm\ Q(X)\ $

For $\rm\ c=0\ $ it specializes to the obvious case: $\rm\ X\mid P(X) \iff  P(0)=0$

If $\rm\ c\ne 0\ $ reduce to $\rm\ c=0\ $ by a shift: $\rm\ X\!-\!c\mid P(X) \iff X\mid P(X\!+\!c) \iff P(c)=0 $

---

It is helpful to be aware of the following simple equivalences.

**Theorem** $\ $ TFAE for a polynomial $\,f\in R[x],\,$ and $\,a\in R\,$ a commutative ring.

$(0)\ \ \ f = (x\!-\!a)q + r\ $ for some $\,q\in R[x],\ r\in R\ \ \ $ [Monic Linear Division Algorithm]

$(1)\ \ \ f\bmod (x\!-\!a) = f(a)\ \ \ \  $ [Remainder Theorem]

$(2)\ \ \ f(a) = 0\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!a\mid f\ \ \ \  $ [Factor Theorem]

**Proof** $\ (0\Rightarrow 1)\ \ \ f = (x\!-\!a)q + r\,\overset{\large x\,=\,a}\Longrightarrow\, r=f(a)\,\Rightarrow\,f\bmod x\!-\!a = r = f(a) $

$(1\Rightarrow 2)\ \ \ f\bmod x\!-\!a = f(a) = 0\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!a\mid f$

$(2\Rightarrow 0)\ \ \ g := f-f(a)\,$ has $\,g(a) = 0\ $ so $\ g = f-f(a) = (x\!-\!a)q$

**Remark** $ $ The polynomial division algorithm always works in any polynomial ring for divisors that are *monic* (lead coef $= 1$ or a unit) such as $\,x-a\,$ above, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242).

Answer (score 4):

By the division algorithm, if $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are *any* polynomials, and $a(x)\neq 0$, then there exist unique $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that
$$b(x) = q(x)a(x) + r(x),\qquad r(x)=0\text{ or }\deg(r)\lt \deg(a).$$

Let $b(x) = p(x)$, and $a(x)=x-c$. Then $r(x)$ must be constant (since it is either zero or of degree strictly smaller than one), so
$$b(x) = q(x)(x-c) + r.$$
Now evaluate at $x=c$.

**Note.** I find it strange that you say that this is "easy if $c$ is a root of $p(x)$". The Factor Theorem (that $x-c$ divides $p(x)$ when $c$ is a root of $p(x)$) is a *corollary* of this result. How exactly do you prove it without this?

Comment: Is it required to say that $F[x]$ is an Euclidean Domain for any field $F$?

Comment: Perhaps you could go on and prove that? Hint : use induction on the degree of the polynomial you divide.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: "Required" by whom? It all depends on what background material you are allowed to assume and what you are not.

Comment: Actually this result is equivalent to the Factor Theorem, since $P(x)-P(c)$ always has $c$ as a root. Anyhow, I agree with you, usually the Factor Theorem is proven by proving this result first.

Comment: @Arturo well I knew this result it is basically what he does in the book but I guess what I was missing was just plug c in for x

Comment: @Kannappan The assumption that the Divison Algorithm holds in $F[x]$ is equivalent to assuming that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. The former simply uses more elementary language, so it will be accessible to readers who have not yet studied the abstract concept of Euclidean domains.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it goes : the polynomials $\{1, (x-c), (x-c)^2, \dots \}$ form a basis of the vector space $F[x]$. Write
$$
p(x) = a_0 + a_1 (x-c) + a_2 (x-c)^2 + \dots + a_n (x-c)^n.
$$
Then 
$$
p(x) = (x-c) \left( a_1 + a_2(x-c)^2 + \dots + a_n (x-c)^{n-1} \right)+ a_0 
$$
and you can see that $p(c) = a_0$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: As Bill Dubuque says, division algorithm works too, I just thought I'd be more explicit. Actually this also provides one way to show the Euclidean algorithm works (for the polynomial $(x-c)$ in particular) : write $p(x) = p((x-c) + c)$ and in the expression of $p(x)$ as $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, you replace $x^k$ by $(x-c+c)^k$ and expand this by using the binomial theorem and keeping the $(x-c)$ terms together.

Comment: While that works in this special case, it doesn't generalize to higher degree divisors. It's really the division algorithm that is the essence of the matter here, i.e. that $\rm\:F[x]\:$ is a *Euclidean* domain. More generally, in any polynomial ring the polynomial long division algorithm works for any divisor whose leading coefficient is a *unit*, i.e. invertible.

Comment: I know it doesn't for higher degree polynomials, but this argument is often forgotten and sometimes more intuitive than the Euclidean algorithm. Being a fan of intuition myself I like to recall this argument every once in a while.

Comment: One can also do this *ring* theoretically by exploiting the shift automorphism $\rm\ x\to x+c\:,\:$ see my remark in my answer.

Comment: One needs to be very careful that such a proof isn't *circular*. To prove that $\rm\:\{\:(x-c)^{\:i\:}\}\:$ spans $\rm\:F[x]\:$ one very natural approach is to repeatedly apply the Division Algorithm  to  obtain the Horner form $\rm\:p(x)\ =\ a_0 + (x-c)(a_1 + (x-c)(a_2+(x-c)(a_3+\:\cdots\:)))\:.\:$ Did you have in mind some other method that is not so blatantly circular?

Comment: Automorphisms sends a basis to another, do they? If $\phi$ maps $x$ to $x-c$ then it sends the canonical basis to the other one. I don't think you need a proof to show that the powers of $x$ are a basis of $F[x]$ since we literally define $F[x]$ as linear combinations of powers of $x$. Proving that $\phi$ is an automorphism is fairly trivial and I don't think it relies on the division algorithm. I think you're just worrying too much about technicalities. If you don't wanna use the automorphism method, robjohn's technique works too by using induction on the degree.

Comment: I didn't realize that you were (implicitly) invoking the fact that the shift $\rm\ x\to x+c\ $ is an  automorphism of $\rm\:F[x]\:.\:$ Perhaps you should *explicitly* mention that so it is clear what is intended. As for technicalities, they are *essential* in mathematics.

Comment: I don't need this at all, there are plenty of ways to do this, one is to show that $x^k = x^k-c^k + c^k = (x-c)(polynomial) + c^k$ and use induction, another one would be 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (x-c+c)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \left( \sum_{i=0}^k \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i \end{pmatrix}  (x-c)^i c^{n-i} \right) 
$$
and you have your basis right there. Like I said, you're worrying too much about technicalities. If you are still worried, I can't do much.

Comment: Of course there are many ways to do it - some correct, some circular. But, alas, I have no clue from what you wrote in your answer which alternative applies. Hence my remarks.  Good mathematical exposition does not leave such doubts in the mind of the reader. It would be nice it you elaborated in your answer *precisely* how you propose to deduce said elements form a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that
$$
p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k
$$
Then
$$
p(x)-p(c)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x^k-c^k)
$$
For each $k$, we have that
$$
\frac{x^k-c^k}{x-c}=x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}c+x^{k-3}c^2+\dots+xc^{k-2}+c^{k-1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{p(x)-p(c)}{x-c}
&=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}c+x^{k-3}c^2+\dots+xc^{k-2}+c^{k-1})\\
&=q(x)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $p(x)=q(x)(x-c)+p(c)$, which is another way of writing $p(x)$ divided by $x-c$ leaves a remainder of $p(c)$ since the degree of $p(c)$, $0$, is less than the degree of $x-c$, $1$.

Comment: This is essentially a different way of handling the modular equivalences in Bill Dubuque's answer.

Comment: Yes, by *linearity*, $\rm\ x-c\ |\ p(x)-p(c)\ $ reduces to the well-known monomial case $\rm\ p(x) = x^k\:.\:$ In terms of congruences $\rm\ x\:\equiv\:c\ \Rightarrow\ x^k\:\equiv\:c^k\ \Rightarrow\ \sum a_k x^k\:\equiv \sum a_k c^k\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:p(x)\:\equiv\:p(c)\:.$

Answer (score 2):

"$p(x)$ divided by $x-c$ has remainder $p(c)$"

is equivalent to

"$p(x+c)$ divided by $x$ has remainder $p(c)$",

which is equivalent to

"$q(x)$ divided by $x$ has remainder $q(0)$",

which is obvious.

**EDIT.** This is essentially the argument used By Gauss in Article 43 of the **Disquisitiones Arithmeticae**. A French translation is available at Internet Archive and at Google Books:

- [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/stream/recherchesarithm00gaus#page/28/mode/1up),
- [Google Books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=0LdUAAAAYAAJ&dq=intitle%3Arecherches%20inauthor%3Agauss&hl=fr&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Yes, I like to show this way too - but it has pedagogical subtleties - see my remark.