# If $f(x)=(x-2)q(x)-8$ for polynomial $q$, and $x+2$ is a factor of $f(x)$, find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, interpolation, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Given:
>
> $f(x)=(x-2)q(x) -8$, where $q(x)$ is a polynomial
>
> $(x+2)$ is a factor of $f(x)$
>
> Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x^2-4)$.

I know the answer is $-2x-4$, but I do not know the working behind it?

Comment: Hint:  write $f(x)=(x^2-4)q(x)+r(x)$. where $r(x)=ax+b$.   All you need is two values for $r(x)$.

Comment: I actually got up to that step but I do not know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Wait... I think I have solved it... Thank you!

Comment: @lulu That's the hard way. Instead pull out the factor $\,x+2\,$ in common with $f$ and the modulus $\,x^2-4\,$ and then you don't need to solve any equations - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An *easy* way: use $\,{ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c)} = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor out $\,a = x\!+\!2$

$\,\ \color{#0a0}{x\!+\!2\mid f}\,\Rightarrow\, f\bmod x^2\!-\!4\,$ $=\, (x\!+\!2)\underbrace{\Bigg[\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{f}{x\!+\!2}}\bmod x\!-\!\color{#c00}2\Bigg]\! = (x\!+\!2)\left[\dfrac{f(\color{#c00}{2})}{\color{#c00}2\!+\!2}\right]}_{\textstyle\!\!\!\!\! \begin{align} \color{#0a0}f\,\bmod x\!-\!\color{#c00}2\ &=\ f(\color{#c00}{2}) = -8\\ \color{#0a0}{x\!+\!2}\,\bmod x\!-\!\color{#c00}2\ &= \color{#c00}2\!+\!2\end{align}}\! = (x\!+\!2)\left[-2\right]$

**Remark** $\ $ As I explain in the linked answer, using this distributive law often greatly simplifies computations by reducing the modulus, e.g. above it reduces the modulus to have degree one, viz. $\,x\!-\!2,\,$ and such mods are easy: $\,\color{#0a0}{g(x)}\bmod x\!-\color{#c00}2\!\  =\ g(\color{#c00}2)\,$ by the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94729/242). Further this optimization may eliminate the need to use CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem, so elminates possibly complicated computation of modular inverses.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) for a more complex and general example of the above method for polynomials, which highlights its relationship with **Lagrange interpolation** and **Taylor's formula**.

Comment: Good point, much easier.

Comment: The feeling of learning the distributive method is probably what our ancestors felt like when they figured out how to use fire

Comment: I'm a bit puzzle on the modular arthimetic property works for idvision, how did you arrive at what $ f \mod x-2 $ from $ f \mod x^2 -4$ , I got the first line but how did you move to the next line from that

Comment: @Buraian The underbraced expression tells how to compute $\,\color{#0a0}{g = \dfrac{f}{x+2}}\bmod x\!-\!\color{#c00}2,\,$ i.e. simply evaluate the top & bottom at $\,x=\color{#c00}2.\,$ Indeed $\,f (x)= (x\!+\!2)g(x)\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}2) = (\color{#c00}2\!+\!2)g(\color{#c00}2).\,$ I edited the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

We know that when $f(x)$ is divided by $x-2$ the remainder is $-8$, so
$$f(x) = (x-2)q(x) - 8$$
for some polynomial $q(x)$.

We also know that $x+2$ is a factor of of $f(x)$.  This means that when we plug in $x=-2$ to $f(x)$ we should get $0$.  So
$$0 = (-2 -2)q(-2) - 8$$
$$8 = -4q(-2)$$
$$-2 = q(-2)$$
This last result tells us that when $q(x)$ is divided by $x+2$, the remainder is $-2$, so for some polynomial $u(x)$ we have
$$q(x)=(x+2)u(x) - 2$$
Combining these results, we now know that
$$f(x) = (x-2)((x+2)u(x) - 2) - 8$$
$$f(x) = (x^2-4)u(x) -2(x-2) - 8$$
$$f(x) = (x^2 - 4)u(x) -2x - 4$$
and now you can see the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2-4$.