# Why is this polynomial irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have this polynomial:
$$ x^4 - 11x^3 + 27x^2 - 11x -13$$
And I need to check that is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. What I saw is that if it has a factorisation 3-1, it happens that must have a root that must be one of $\pm 1, \pm 13$, and any of them is. For the case of 2-2 I'm not able to see an easy way to attack it. I have a hint that says *evaluate $f(x+a)$ for an adecuate $ a $ and then use the Einsenstein criterion to finish* but I don't know how to get this appropiate $ a $, and why if I find it, it would finish the problem. Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\,f\,$ [has discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+Discriminant(x%5E4-11x%5E3%2B27x%5E2-11x-13,x)) $\,\color{#c00}7^3 11^2 19\,$ and $\ f(x) \equiv (x-1)^4 \pmod{\color{#c00} 7}\ $ is a *prime power*.

Thus $\,f(x+1) = x^4-7x^3+14x-7 \equiv x^4\pmod{7}\ $ does the trick. Below is why.

**Hint** $\ $ Recall that the [key idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23877/242) behind the Eisenstein criteria is that polynomials satisfying the criterion are, mod $\,p,\,$ powers of a prime, viz. $\,\equiv x^n,\,$ and products of primes always factor uniquely. The same works for its  shift $\,(x-c)^n,\,$ so we seek primes $\,p\,$ such that, mod $\,p,\,$ the polynomial is congruent to such a power (e.g. for motivation: [cyclotomic case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93628/242)). One can show that the only primes $\,p\,$ that can yield such powers are those dividing the discriminant of the polynomial. Indeed, if $\,f\equiv a (x-c)^n,\,\ n> 1\,$ then $\,f\,$ and $\,f'\,$ have a common root $\,x\equiv c,\,$  hence their [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) $\, R(f,f')\equiv 0.\,$ But this is, up to sign, the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_polynomial) of $\,f\,$ (presumed monic).

Comment: Why you know that $ a=-1$ is the useful one? (I mean, how you found it quickly? Does exist an algorithm or a rule?)

Comment: @MonsieurGalois That's explained in the Hint.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still reading it.

Comment: As I understood, the key idea of the Einsenstein criteria is sending the polynomials to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ to get if it's reducible there, no? So if you get a polynomial there, you can change the variable $ x $ to $ x-c $ and check reducibility of it. This is the reason of why is useful the Einsenstein criteria in this case. Is what you're saying?