# Proof of Eisentein's Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $R$ be a factorial ring and $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i \in R[X]$ a primitive polynomial with degree > 0. Furthermore, let $p\in R$ be a prime element and
$p\nmid a_n, \ \ p\mid a_i, \forall i<n, \ \ p^2\nmid a_0$. Then $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$.

I will now do the proof as it is done in my book (Algebra - Siegfried Bosch, 8.ed. p67-68). The proof is indirect.

We assume $f$ is reducible in $R[X]$. We then have a decomposition 
$f=gh, g=\sum_{i=0}^r b_iX^i, h=\sum_{i=0}^sc_iX^i$, where $r+s=n, r>0, s>0$. It then follows that

$a_n=b_rc_s\ne 0, \ \ p\nmid b_r, \ \ p\nmid c_s, \\
a_0=b_0c_0, \ \ p\mid b_0c_0, \ \ p^2\nmid b_0c_0$

and we assume without loss of generality, that $p\mid b_0, p\nmid c_0$. Let then be $t<r$ maximal with $p\mid b_\tau$ for $0\le \tau \le t$. We set $b_i=0$ for $i>r$ and $c_i=0$ for $i>s$ and get
$a_{t+1}=b_0c_{t+1} + ... + b_{t+1}c_0$.

We have $p\nmid a_{t+1}$, because $b_0c_{t+1},...,b_tc_1$ are divisable by $p$, but not $b_{t+1}c_0$. It follows that $t+1=n$, because of our requirements about $f$, and therefore $r=n,s=0$ in contradiction to $s>0$.

I understand the proof, but the point is, I can not see why the requirements $p^2\nmid a_0$ or that $f$ be primitive is needed. It has not been used.

Comment: $p^2\nmid a_0$ is used to say that $p^2\nmid b_0 c_0$, so that one of them is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Thank you, that was unexpectedly easy! Do you have an idea about the primitivity, too?

Comment: Insight is gained by [presenting the proof more conceptually,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1997100/242) to highlight that the key idea employed is that *products of primes factor uniquely*.

Comment: If $h\in R[X]$ with $\deg h = d > 0$ isn't primitive, you can write it as $c \cdot g$ with a non-unit $c\in R$ and $g \in R[X]$ such that $\deg g = d > 0$, so it's not irreducible.