# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} {k \choose l}$ is divisible by p

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime. 
How do we prove the following?

> $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} {k \choose l}$ is divisible by p for $0\leq l \leq p-2$

I have brute-forced verified this for the special case $p=5$, but I fail to see a trick that will let me prove this for arbitrary prime $p$.

Just to give some context, I am attempting to solve this [Irreducibility issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93618/irreducibility-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1). If I can prove the above statement, I should be able to apply Eisenstein's Criterion and be done.

Comment: I think you are missing a hypothesis somewhere.

Comment: This is not clear.  What exactly are you asking for, say, $p=5$?

Comment: I'm asking how to prove this for arbitrary prime p.

Comment: Prove what exactly?   If I take $p=5,l=3$ what is it you are trying to show?

Comment: For which value of $l$ do you get that the sum is 1?

Comment: Please, answer the specific question.  For $p=5,l=3$ what is it you are trying to prove?  You claim to have solved the problem for $p=5$...what is it you solved?

Comment: Actually, I have made a horrible mistake in my question. Let me edit it.

Comment: Your sum $\sum_{k=0}^l {k \choose l}$ has no $p$ in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{k}l = \binom{p}{l+1}$$ holds for all positive integers $p$. This can be proven by induction on $p$ and by using Pascal's identity.