# Eisenstein's Criterion with an example

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, eisenstein-integers

Wolfram Alpha says $x^5 -x^2 +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there any way to prove it by Eisenstein's Criterion?

I tried to translate this function. I translated the function a couple of times by some integers, but none of the translations worked. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Why not use rational root theorem?

Comment: @Andrei Polynomials can have no roots and yet be reducible. Consider $(x^2 +1)(x^2 + 2)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, for example.

Comment: No, it's not possible to apply Eisenstein's criterion in this case. The discriminant of $f$ is $7 \cdot 431$, and modulo these primes $f$ does not factor as a power of a single irreducible linear factor. Bill Dubuque had a nice [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981311/x612x549x496x399x254x15-is-irreducible-over-bbb-zx/2981918#2981918) on this, but it unfortunately seems to have been deleted... Keith Conrad has some good [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) on Eisenstein polynomials and totally ramified primes, too.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually, here's a similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849942/) that is close to the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050666/242) an Eisenstein shift cannot work. But it follows easily from irreducibility mod $2\!:\,$ over $\Bbb F_2$ it has no roots so no linear factors, so if it splits it has an irreducible quadratic factor $g$, therefore in  $\, \Bbb F_2[x]/g \cong \Bbb F_{\color{#c00}4}\!:\,$ $\,\color{#c00}{x^3 = 1}\,$ so  $\ 0 = f = x^2(\color{#c00}{x^3})-x^2+1 = 1,\,$ contradiction.

**Remark** $ $ Above is a special case of a general  [polynomial irreducibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853656/242) over finite fields - which is an an *efficient* analog of the impractical [Pocklington-Lehmer integer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test).

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand $ (x+a)^5 - (x+a)^2 + 1$

Compare the coefficients of $x^4 , x^2$.

> Show that $ \gcd ( 5a, 10a^3 - 1) = 1$.

$ $

> Hence conclude that Einstein's criterion cannot prove it is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you very much.