# Using Eisenstein criterion show that $x^3+x^2-2x-1$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I tried for few primes but they do not satisfy Eisenstein criterion.Also is there any approach other than brute force with the help of which we can find that prime.

Comment: Constant term is -1, and no prime divides -1. You'll have to use something like x=t+a for some appropriate choice of a, to get Eisenstein's criterion to work.

Comment: You can find further examples in the linked dupe. The method I describe there yields a simple *algorithm* to find such a prime (or prove that it does not exist).

Comment: Note also that none of $-1$ or $1$ is a root, so you can use rational root theorem to get the irreducibility in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply Eisenstein's criterion to $(x+2)^3+(x+2)^2-2(x+2)-1$, with $p=7$.

Comment: Also is there any approach other than brute force with the help of which we can find that prime and $t$ in $(x+t)$?

Comment: @Mahesh I explained that in my answer. There is even a link to the Alpha computation.

Comment: How did you know to substitute $x$ with $x + 2$ and to use $p = 7$??

Comment: @Junglemath I did *not* know. I tried $x+1$, $x-1$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reducite criterium.

I.e., consider the polynomial over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$.I.e., we get $X^3 + X^2 +1$. If this reduced polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (this theorem is known as the reducite criterium).

This polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (it has no roots, this is easily seen).

Hence, by the reducite criterium it follows that $X^3 + X^2 - 2X -1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to pull the Eisenstein shift out of a hat like magic. I explain how to find it below.

**Hint** $\, \bmod\color{#c00}7\!:\,\ f(x)  \equiv (x\!-\!2)^{3} \ $ is a *prime power*.

So Eisenstein works on $\,g(x) = f(x\!+\!2)  \equiv x^3\ $ by 
 $\,g(0) = f(2)\equiv 7\not\equiv 0\pmod{\!49}$

**Remark** $\ $ Recall that the [key idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23877/242) behind the Eisenstein criteria is that polynomials satisfying the criterion are, mod $\,p,\,$ powers of a prime, viz. $\,\equiv x^n,\,$ and products of primes always factor *uniquely*. The same works for its  shift $\,(x-c)^n,\,$ so we seek primes $\,p\,$ such that, mod $\,p,\,$ the polynomial is congruent to such a power (e.g. for motivation: [cyclotomic case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93628/242)). The only primes $\,p\,$ that can yield such powers are those dividing the discriminant (here [by Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+PolynomialDiscriminant%5Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2-2x-1,x%5D) = $\,\color{#c00}7^2).\,$  Indeed, if $\,f\equiv a (x-c)^n,\,\ n> 1\,$ then $\,f\,$ and $\,f'\,$ have a common root $\,x\equiv c,\,$  hence their [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) $\, R(f,f')\equiv 0.\,$ But this is, up to sign, the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_polynomial) of $\,f\,$ (presumed monic).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$, then what is $f(x+2)$?