# Is $x^{20} +x^{15}+ x^{10}+x^5+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is $x^{20} +x^{15}+ x^{10}+x^5+1$  irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

I think if $y=x^5$, then $P(y)=y^{4} +y^{3}+ y^{2}+y+1 =\displaystyle \frac{y^5-1}{y-1}$, $5$ is prime, then $P(y)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ or $\mathbb{Q}[x^5]$ , how do I show that it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Are you familiar with cyclotomic polynomials or Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: see this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215042/irreducibility-of-xp-1-ldots-x1

Comment: I´m familiar with  Eisenstein's criterion

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^{20}+x^{15}+x^{10}+x^5+1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
& (x^5-1)f(x) &=& x^{25} - 1\\
\implies & ((x+1)^5-1)f(x+1) &=& (x+1)^{25} - 1\\
\implies & ((x+1)^5-1)f(x+1) &=& (x+1)^{25} - 1 \pmod 5\\
\end{array}$$ Simplifying this, what can you say about the coefficients of $f(x+1)$?

Comment: just one doubt if f(x+1) is irreducible , then f(x) is too because homomorphism , i can say that f($x^5+1$)  is irreducible , then f($x^5$) is irreducible too?

Comment: For the $1^{st}$ part of your statement, $f(x)$ reducible $\implies f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ for some non-trivial $g(x), h(x) \implies f(x+1) = g(x+1)h(x+1)$ reducible. The contra-positive is $f(x+1)$ irreducible $\implies f(x)$ irreducible. So the $1^{st}$ part of statement is true. For the $2^{nd}$ part, $f(x^5)$ reducible $\implies f(x^5) = g(x)h(x)$ for non-trivial $g(x),h(x)$. However, there is no obvious transform to express $f(x^5+1)$ in terms of $g(x), h(x)$. This means there is no reason to believe irreducibility of $f(x^5+1)$ will lead to irreducibility of $f(x^5)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = x^{20}+x^{15}+x^{10}+x^5+1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
& (x^5-1)f(x) &=& x^{25} - 1\\
\implies & ((x+1)^5-1)f(x+1) &=& (x+1)^{25} - 1\\
\implies & ((x+1)^5-1)f(x+1) &=& (x+1)^{25} - 1 \pmod 5\\
\iff     & ((x^5+1)-1)f(x+1) &=& (x^5+1)^5 - 1 \pmod 5\\
\iff     & x^5 f(x+1) &=& (x^{25}+1) - 1 \pmod 5\\
\iff     &     f(x+1) &=& x^{20} \pmod 5
\end{array}$$
This implies aside from the leading term $x^{20}$, the coefficients of $x^{k}$ in $f(x+1)$ where $0 \le k < 20$ are all divisible by $5$. Notice the constant term in $f(x+1)$ is $f(1) = 5$ which
is not divisible by $5^2$. By Eisenstein's criterion, 
$f(x+1)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. As a corollary, so does $f(x)$.