# Is polynomial $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ a prime number, is the polynomial

$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}$$
 irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else can you write it as? After that, can you shift $x$ and make the polynomial Eisenstein at $p$?

Comment: See also: [Irreducibility of $X^{p-1} + \ldots + X+1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215042/irreducibility-of-xp-1-ldots-x1) or
[Irreducibility issue](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93618/irreducibility-issue) or [Eisenstein Criterion with a twist](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/eisenstein-criterion-with-a-twist)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mr. Eisenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) certainly thinks so!

The polynomial can be rewritten as $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$. Setting $x=(y+1)$ has no effect on (ir)reducibility of the polynomial; doing so and applying the binomial theorem yields:
$$\frac{(y+1)^p-1}{(y+1)-1}=\frac{1}{y}\sum_{k=1}^{p}\binom{p}{k}y^{k}=y^{p-1}+\binom{p}{p-1}y^{p-2}+\ldots+\binom{p}{2}y^1+\binom{p}{1}y^0$$

Since all the coefficients apart from the leading one are divisible by $p$ and the constant term is too small to be divisible by $p^2$, we can apply the criterion and conclude that the polynomial is irreducible over rationals (and thus also over integers).

Comment: How do we know that $\sum_{k=0}^l {k \choose l}$ is divisible by p for $0\leq l \leq p-2$? I have brute-forced verified this for the special case $p=5$, but I fail to see a trick that will let me prove this for arbitrary prime $p$.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Are you sure you are interested in the sum you specified (it doesn't include any mention of $p$ and is actually equal to $1$ since all the terms are zero apart from the one with $k=l$). When it comes to the sum in my answer, it's each binomial coefficient on its own being divisible by $p$ already: Since $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ and the numerator is divisible by $p$ while all the multiplied terms in the denominator are strictly smaller than $p$, the whole binomial coefficient is divisible by $p$ too.

Comment: I meant $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} {k \choose l}$. Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 5):

$1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{p-1}=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$. So if we set $x=y+1$, then our polynomial becomes $\frac{(y+1)^p-1}{y}=y^{p-1}+py^{p-2}+\frac{p(p-1)}{2}y^{p-3}+\ldots+p$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein. But since $x \mapsto y+1$ is an isomomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[y]$, our original polynomial is irreducible as well.