# A question about proving irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra

If p is a prime, prove that $$x^{p-1}-x^{p-2}+x^{p-3}-\cdots-x+1$$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Hope somebody can show me some details. Thanks

Comment: Look at $f(-x-1)$. Expand it out using the binomial theorem, and apply Eisenstein.

Comment: Or f(x+1) and use Eisenstein"s :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/eisenstein-criterion-with-a-twist?lq=1

Comment: Another duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408072/is-polynomial-1xx2-cdotsxp-1-irreducible?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that $p$ is odd; otherwise the alternating signs don't match up. It's well known that $F(x)x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+x^{p-3}+\cdots +x+1$ is irreducible, but I'll reproduce the proof here.

$F(x)$ is irreducible iff $F(x-1)$ is irreducible. But
$$
F(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=\frac{(y+1)^p-1}{y}
$$
Where $y=x-1$. Expanding using the binomial theorem, this is
$$
y^{p-1}\binom{p}{p}+y^{p-2}\binom{p}{p-1}+\cdots+y\binom{p}{2}+\binom{p}{1}
$$
But by Eisenstein's criterion, this is irreducible, as $p\mid \binom{p}{k}$ for $1\le k \le p-1$, and $p^2\nmid \binom{p}{1}$.

Now the original polynomial, $x^{p-1}-x^{p-2}+\cdots -x+1$ is simply $F(-x)$, so it is irreducible as well.