# Checking If x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1 Irreducible over Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How I can check if the polynomial $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1$ is Irreducible or Not over $Z$ ?

Here, Eisenstein's criteria isn't applicable neither *Mod P* irreducible Test.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Eisenstein's Criterion is often used in this case after substituting, say,  $x=y+1$.  Then the polynomial becomes $y^4+5y^3+10y^2+10y+5$ which is obviously irreducible by Eisenstein for $p=5$, and this implies the original polynomial is irreducible as well.

Comment: Really? Can we do like this?

Comment: Sure.  If you take a look at the linked post here -> https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87609/254075 called Eisenstein with a twist, it shows that same trick can be used to show the $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible for any $p$.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you know how it factors over $\mathbb{C}$, and from that the only way in which it factors over $\mathbb{R}$: 
$$\left(x-e^{2\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{-2\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{4\pi i/5}\right)\left(x-e^{-4\pi i/5}\right)$$

$$\left(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/5)+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos(4\pi/5)+1\right)$$

Since $2\cos(2\pi/5)=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}-1)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, you can conclude it is not reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Suppose you did not know the value of $2\cos(2\pi/5)$ or $2\cos(4\pi/5)$ with radicals. You can still say that the only way to factor this polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ (up to unit scalars) is

$$\left(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/5)+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos(4\pi/5)+1\right)$$

Now, if the polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, then this *must* be its factorization (well, or negate both factors), since the only thing you could play with would be scalars. But scaling to give one of these factors the leading term $nx^2$, the other would have to have leading term $\frac{1}{n}x^2$, with $\frac{1}{n}$ not an integer.

So the only way the polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ is if $2\cos(2\pi/5)$ is an integer. It's clearly positive and less than $2$. So it would have to be $1$. But $\cos(2\pi/5)$ is not equal to $1/2$, because $\cos(2\pi/6)$ *is* equal to $1/2$.

Comment: how do you know what $2\cos(2π/5)$ is, just curious

Comment: One answer is just knowing that's what it is. Like knowing that $\cos(\pi/6)=\sqrt{3}/2$. But if you want to derive _why_, angle addition gives: $\cos(5x)=\cos(x+4x)=\cdots=16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x)$. So with $x=2\pi/5$, you have that $\cos(2\pi/5)$ is a solution to $1=16X^5-20X^3+5X$. Moving terms around and factoring out the obvious factor, $0=(X-1)(16X^4+16X^3-4X^2-4X+1)$. $X=\cos(2\pi/5)$ is clearly not $1$. So it's a solution to $0=16X^4+16X^3-4X^2-4X+1$. This is a perfect square: $0=(4X^2+2X-1)^2$. There are two solutions from this, and only one is positive: $(-1+\sqrt{5})/4$.

Comment: oh well. i wouldve never gotten anywhere close to that. but thank you :)

Comment: I edited to offer a solution that does not require knowing the radical value of $\cos(2\pi/5)$.

Answer (score 0):

***For any prime p, the pth cyclotomic polynomial***

$$p(x) = \frac{x^p-1}{x-1}= x^{p-1}+ x^{p-2}+...x+1$$

**Is Irreducible over Q.**
*And If its Primitive polynomial than its also Irreducible over Z.*